# Ajax запрос возвращает ошибку 404 в приложении на Cordova

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

Пишу ajax запрос в приложении на Cordova. Он работает если запустить приложение в браузере или эмуляторе, но возвращает ошибку, если запустить приложение на телефоне. Результат выполнения ajax-запроса: `error{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}`

Текст скрипта я не меняю, но почему-то из браузера на компьютере скрипт срабатывает, а в приложении нет. Из-за чего может возникнуть такая проблема?

Comment: а у меня на Android SDK 28 не работает. Хотя на 27 еще работало, ищу причину, вы не сталкивались ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в файл `config.xml` строчки

```
<access origin="*" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

всё заработало